# Pass value to colorbox on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello Guys please help me out,

I want pass Data-id value to Color Box Popup 
so what sholud i have to do..please help me

or is there any other way to do the same..

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements

$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"70%", height:"500px;"});

});
</script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<li><a class='inline' href="#inline_content" data-id="1">ABC</a></li>
<li><a class='inline' href="#inline_content" data-id="2">DEF</a></li>
<li><a class='inline' href="#inline_content" data-id="3">XYZ</a></li>
```

**Color Box Popup**

This is pop window on same page.

```
<div style='display:none'>
<div id='inline_content'>
   Data-id = "" // Here I want to display data-id of clicked Post, Like if we click ABC Post than in Popup data-id is equal to 1, if click XYZ tha data-id equql to 3 in Popup 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try This as `href = "#intent_content?d=<?php echo $id;?>"`

Comment: it will not work i treid it before...:(

Comment: As is, you should have a 500 error.

Comment: Plus, you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and are open to mysql injections. Please, add details about the desired behaviour and the current behaviour (javascript error, server error, ...)

Comment: Maybe you want something like this ? `<div id="inline_content" data-galid="<?php echo $gal_id ?>">` and then use `$('#inline_content').data('galid')` ?

Comment: Now this is simple code, please tell me if there is any possible way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code..

```
<div id='popupdiv'>
<div id='intent_content'>..
```

above for html..

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#popupdiv').hide();
    $('.inline').click(function(){
       var data_id = $(this).data('id');
       $('#popupdiv').show();
       $('#inline_content').html("Data-id ="+data_id);
    });
   });
```

and you have to give an id to that `div` which contains `style="display:none";` so that by using that id you can change the css to `block` or `else`

Comment: Gratitude..! Enjoy Scripting

Comment: its only displaying data id other content are not visble which is `#inline_content` div.

or will you please tell if i have t0 pass data-id value in any php variable i.e `$galid`

Comment: I have said you that you need to allow some id within your parent div of `#intent_content` div like this `<div id='popupdiv'>` instead of `<div style='display:none'>` and you can simply hide it using jquery see my edited answer

Comment: Where you want to apply this value within your page

Comment: Then you are getting it one over there